Negative log-likelihood, high BIC, high R-squared, low error, using a difference-in-differences (DiD) methodology
I am trying to see the impact of Brexit on UK imports. My dependent variable are EU exports to the rest of world. I have monthly data from 2013 to 2023, also data is in billions of GBP.
When I do difference-in differences (DiD), I get the following result:

The R-squared and error seems to be good, but the log-likelihood is negative and BIC seems to be huge.
I am not sure how to interpret this, as it seems to be contradictive.
This is the new code I ran for Gaussian:
Call:
lm(formula = uk_imports_scaled ~ treatment + eu_exports_scaled + 
    did + covid, data = Import_analysis2)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-4.4189 -0.8839 -0.1384  0.7455  4.9058 

Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        8.291e+00  1.046e+00   7.926    1e-12 ***
treatment         -6.005e+00  2.038e+00  -2.947  0.00382 ** 
eu_exports_scaled  3.667e-02  3.196e-03  11.472  < 2e-16 ***
did                1.242e-11  4.400e-12   2.823  0.00553 ** 
covid             -6.799e-01  1.409e+00  -0.483  0.63017    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.374 on 127 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8033,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7971 
F-statistic: 129.7 on 4 and 127 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

the whole code
# Data preparation
Import_analysis2 <- Import_analysis2 %>%
  mutate(Date = as.yearmon(Date, format = "%Y %b"),
         treatment = if_else(Date >= as.yearmon("2020-02"), 1, 0),
         covid = if_else(Date >= as.yearmon("2020-03"), 1, 0),
         did = treatment * eu_exports)

# Gaussian Model
gaussian_model <- lm(uk_imports ~ treatment + eu_exports + did + covid, 
                     data = Import_analysis2)
summary(gaussian_model)
tidy_gaussian <- tidy(gaussian_model)
print(tidy_gaussian)


Please include your summary output as text (in a code block delimited by triple-backticks (```), not as a screenshot/image

Does your treatment variable really  switch from 0 to 1 in early 2020? Shouldn’t it be much earlier? I notice considerable overlap with the Covid dummy. Maybe this is accurate, but I can’t be sure.

Log likelihood and BIC (and other similar measures) cannot be evaluated on their own. They are useful for comparing models. See, e.g. this thread. If you divide imports and exports by (say) 1000 I believe you will get different values, but the meaning is just the same.
However, if you are trying to look at the effect of Brexit on UK imports, you have longitudinal data and should be doing analysis that accounts for this. It looks like you have simply divided it into "before" and "after", with Brexit as a treatment. You say you have 120 months of data.
Also, in the text you say your dependent variable is EU exports, but in your your formula you have your DV as UK imports and your IV as EU exports, but that is probably a typo.

Thank you so much for your input, this is really helpful! Yes, it's a typo, DV is UK imports.

Beyond @PeterFlom's excellent answer about the relative nature of metrics like log-likelihood and BIC, you're missing a critical point: never use a Poisson model without considering the possibility of overdispersion. At the very least, you should be using family = "quasipoisson" rather than family = "poisson"; unless you do this you will be making the very strong and usually false assumption that the variance of the conditional distribution is equal to its mean.
More generally, however, it's not obvious in this case why you would be using a Poisson model rather than a good old Gaussian response, as Poisson models are for count data; if it would make any sense to express your response in different units (e.g. millions rather than billions of GBP), then you shouldn't be using a Poisson model.
Finally, the fact that your estimated coefficients for eu_exports and did are tiny ($\lt 10^{-11}$) suggests that something else is wrong with your setup, but without more detail it's hard to diagnose.

Can please edit your question to include both the code you ran and the results, as text? It might also help to include the results of running summary() on your data.

I must be doing something wrong but I am unable to see what. I tried to do it with gaussian, and now eu_exports and did are bigger (3.67e-2, 1.24e-2), but my intercept and treatment have big error (1.05e+9, 2.04e+9 ), but according to p value seem to be significant (1.00e-12, 3.82e- 3). However, treatment estimate is -6.01e+9. Could it be that I am getting data like this because it is a big data set, with big numbers?

We really can't answer without more information - sorry.  Have you tried plotting your data? See my previous comment/request to edit your question with more information.

PS if your problem ends up being one of implementation rather than interpretation, this might be better for Stack Overflow ...

I edited my code...yes I might try with Stack Overflow. Thank you for all the help
